# Authorization for java web app using Azure AD roles

Tags: java, azure, adal

i am looking at the ADAL for java project.
I understand the auth portion ok.

But i cannot find how to authorize the user against the ROLES in the AD.

what have i missed?

thanks

-lp

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD doesn't have any good code samples for java web apps with OpenID Connect at this time.  The best you can do is use a java OpenID Connect library (http://openid.net/developers/libraries/) and modify it to conform to Azure AD's protocol (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code/).

The users roles will show up as claims in the `id_token` if you configure your app correctly.  This sample shows how to do so in .NET: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/

Comment: thanks. But seeing that there is a very nice AD graph api is it as simple as calling the getMemberGroups api ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberGroups